# My app does not update the new version of read-only Core Data sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, core-data

**====MY SOLUTION====**
I solved this by storing the database in the Main Bundle and change the name of the database every time i updated the app.

I did look into refreshing the model etc. but didn't really get that to work as i wanted.

[How i solved this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492471/update-read-only-core-data-sqlite-in-main-bundle)

**====Original question====**

I do apologize that i have asked this question, in different formats, before but i have not been able to solve it, probably due to how i asked the question. I did delete the old questions.

I have an app using a Core Data sqlite read/only database and i am trying to update the app with a new version (version# inbeded in a record) of the database. Whatever i do, except manually clean target and reset simulator, it still read the old database. I need to be able to do this via code.

During the initial design i posted the following to try to solve the same problem: [The initial design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284659/how-to-update-a-pre-populated-core-data-sqlite3-db-in-appstore). Now the database is so big it takes a lot of time to build it at first start.

The process:

> A.) I add the new database version to the XCODE project and also manually add it to the bundle via Xcode
>
> B.) I check what version of the database is used
>
> C.) If there is a new database i delete the old database in the documents directory and then copy the new version from the main bundle to the document directory
>
> D.) In the attached code i also delete the Cache directory and recreate it, I found a number of posts that pointed out that the cache could be the reason. This is just for testing but is still included in the code

Despite this the app still not access the updated sqlite database.

I have a new database version loaded in the main bundle, I have a version parameter "EEEEEE", when i read the current database it has "SSSSSS" parameter so the database should be updated.

I have been working with this problem, and searched the web, for a long time and i just can not understand what is wrong. Why does it not access the new database in the documents directory.

I am appreciate all help i can get. I hope the code doesn't look to weird as i have included my NSLog's that i use to try to understand what is happening.

The trace (NSLog):

```
applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

readQuestion

persistentStoreCoordinator

==>PARAMETER is EEEEEE (000000)

==> Update needed


=======================
====BEFORE REPLACE====
===>CURRENT: SSSSSS: 999999
=======================
replaceDatabase function
=======================

=======================
     DELETE CACHE
=======================

Remove successful

=======================
   CREATE NEW CACHE
=======================

===============================
REMOVE sqlite FROM DOCUMENT DIR
===============================

removeItemAtPath:dbDocumentsPath: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/912962FC-933E-4305-971B-FF094BBD9051/Documents/database.sqlite

=====================================
CHECK IF sqlite EXIST IN DOCUMENT DIR
=====================================

===FILE DOES NOT EXIST===

========================================
MOVE sqlite FROM BUNDLE TO DOCUMENTS DIR
========================================

==>copyItemAtPath:dbBundlePath<<
====================================
CHECK IF sqlite EXIST IN DOCUMENT DIR
=====================================

===FILE EXIST===

readQuestion

=======================
=====AFTER REPLACE=====
=======================
Updated database is SSSSSS

========>STOP<=========
```

Here is the code from the delegate.m, "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
NSLog(@" ");

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

//==CHECK IF DATABASE NEEDS TO BE UPDATED==//
//====Check if database needs to be refreshed====//


AccessQuestionsDB *refreshDB_function = [AccessQuestionsDB new];
qArray = [refreshDB_function readQuestion: 999999];
NSLog(@" ");

//Tell what language DB 
if ([k_DBVERSION isEqualToString:@"999999"]) {
    NSLog(@"==>PARAMETER is SSSSSS (999999)");
} else {
    NSLog(@"==>PARAMETER is EEEEEE (000000)");
}
NSLog(@" ");

//==== CHECK IF DATABASE NEEDS TO BE UPDATED ====//
if ([[qArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString: k_DBVERSION]) {
    // No update needed
    NSLog(@"==> No update needed");
    NSLog(@" ");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"==> Update needed");
    NSLog(@" ");
    NSLog(@" ");
    NSLog(@"=======================");
    NSLog(@"====BEFORE REPLACE====");
    if ([[qArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"000000"]) {
        NSLog(@"===>CURRENT: EEEEEE: %@", [qArray objectAtIndex:2]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"===>CURRENT: SSSSSS: %@", [qArray objectAtIndex:2]);
    }

    [self replaceDatabase];
}

qArray = [refreshDB_function readQuestion: 999999];
NSLog(@" ");
NSLog(@" ");
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@"=====AFTER REPLACE=====");
NSLog(@"=======================");
if ([[qArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"000000"]) {
    NSLog(@"Updated database is EEEEEE");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Updated database is SSSSSS");
}

NSLog(@" "); 
NSLog(@"========>STOP<=========");
NSLog(@" ");

exit(0); //>>>>STOP HERE DURING TESTING

return YES;
}
```

replaceDatabase:

```
- (void)replaceDatabase {
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@"replaceDatabase function");
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@" ");

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// remove old sqlite database from documents directory
NSURL *dbDocumentsURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
NSString *dbDocumentsPath = [dbDocumentsURL path];

//====Cache directory testing====//
//====This is just for testing====//

//===============================//
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@"    DELETE CACHE");
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@" ");
if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] error: NULL]  == YES)
    NSLog (@"Remove successful");
 else 
    NSLog (@"Remove failed");

NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@"    CREATE NEW CACHE");
NSLog(@"=======================");
NSLog(@" ");    

[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

//===============================//
NSLog(@"===============================");
NSLog(@"REMOVE sqlite FROM DOCUMENT DIR");
NSLog(@"===============================");
NSLog(@" ");


if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbDocumentsPath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbDocumentsPath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"removeItemAtPath:dbDocumentsPath: %@",dbDocumentsPath);
    NSLog(@" ");
    
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting sqlite database: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"file does not ExistsAtPath:dbDocumentsPath: %@",dbDocumentsPath);
    NSLog(@" ");
}


NSLog(@"=====================================");
NSLog(@"CHECK IF sqlite EXIST IN DOCUMENT DIR");
NSLog(@"=====================================");
NSLog(@" ");
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbDocumentsPath]) {
    NSLog(@"===FILE EXIST===");
} else {
    NSLog(@"===FILE DOES NOT EXIST===");
}
 NSLog(@" ");    
    

// move new sqlite database from bundle to documents directory
NSLog(@"========================================");
NSLog(@"MOVE sqlite FROM BUNDLE TO DOCUMENTS DIR");
NSLog(@"========================================");
NSLog(@" ");
NSString *dbBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
if (dbBundlePath) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbBundlePath toPath:dbDocumentsPath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"==>copyItemAtPath:dbBundlePath<<");
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error copying sqlite database: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

NSLog(@"=====================================");
NSLog(@"CHECK IF sqlite EXIST IN DOCUMENT DIR");
NSLog(@"=====================================");
NSLog(@" ");
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbDocumentsPath]) {
    NSLog(@"===FILE EXIST===");
} else {
    NSLog(@"===FILE DOES NOT EXIST===");
}
NSLog(@" ");
}
```

persistentStoreCoordinator:

```
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
NSLog(@"persistentStoreCoordinator");

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}  



    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

readQuestion:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)readQuestion: (int)questionNr {

NSLog(@"readQuestion");

NSMutableArray *read_Question = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 0];

NSError *error;
//=========PREPARE CORE DATA DB===========//
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { managedObjectContext = [(xxxxxAppDelegate *)
                                                           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; }
// Define qContext
NSManagedObjectContext *qContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"questions" inManagedObjectContext:qContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSString *qNR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", questionNr];

if (questionNr == 999999) { // This is the call to check if database should be updated
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(question = %@)", @"Hur mycket är 37532 * 3?"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate: pred];
}
else {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idQ = %@)", qNR];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate: pred];
}


NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

NSArray *objects = [qContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {     // If no match refresh database
    [read_Question addObject:@"Update_DB"];
    [read_Question addObject:@"Update_DB"];
    [read_Question addObject:@"Update_DB"];
    [read_Question addObject:@"Update_DB"];
} else {
    matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    [read_Question addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"question"]];
    [read_Question addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"qRightAnswer"]];
    [read_Question addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"qWrongAnswer1"]];
    [read_Question addObject:[matches valueForKey:@"qWrongAnswer2"]];
}

[fetchRequest release];

return [read_Question autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I would guess that your persistentStoreCoordinator has cached the old value, so when you ask for it again it doesn't even need to go to the store to get the value and simply returns the old value.  Perhaps setting persistentStoreCoordinator to nil (and maybe your managedObjectContext) will force a reload and will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, interesting question. I have a theory though. First of all, if I'm reading your code correctly, you are getting a Persistent Store Coordinator in order to figure out the db version. This is creating a Persistent Store Coordinator that refers to the old sqlite file. This is the part I'm not sure about. I suspect that since it has the handle to the old file, even though you delete it, the Persistent Store Coordinator is still referring to the old one. One thing you might want to try is nil-ing out the Persistent Store Coordinator and the Managed object Context after you delete and replace the sqlite file. Also, I would try simply assuming the sqlite is outdated and replacing it before initializing the Persistent Store Coordinator and Managed Object Context.