# How to retrieve image from sqlite database in  iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage, nsdata

In my iPhone App I want to retrieve image from (stored in ) sqlite database table in "BLOB" datafield.

For that I am storing my image in NSData using code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

and I am also able to retrieve image from NSData -> UIImage by code

```
self.img1=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And displaying Image into imageView by

```
imageView2.image=img1;
```

I am storing image (in NSData form) into sqlite database table column (of BLOB Datatype) successfully.

I am using below code to retrieve image from database

```
NSData *imageData2 = [[arraySelect objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"image_column"];   
NSLog(@"imagedata2 in retrive :: %@",imageData2);
```

in NSLOG i am getting the same data stored in database column (in blob  datatype "NSData form" )

Now I am retrieving image by
(while debugging it crashes here and showing meaasge EXE_BAD_ACCESS)

```
self.img3=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
imageview3.image=img3;
```

But I am not getting that image in imageView.
I checked all outlets but they are ok.

So please Help and Suggest what I should  do to get image in imageView from database.

Thanks.

Comment: Well your code looks fine. check what it prints in nslog for img3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and writing images to an SQLite DB for iPhone use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use)

Comment: In particular, my answer in that question contains code that does exactly this, and is what I've used in applications without trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use/643819#643819

Comment: @Brad Larson, thanks for ur suggestion, I read ur code but I am not able to implement it Please guide me in my code where to add that code and in that code for " sqlite3_bind_blob(yourSavingSQLStatement, 2, [dataForImage bytes], [dataForImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);" what is arg1 "your saving sqlstatement  Please help and also guide for retriving  data (second part of code) becoluse here i am using  Array for retriving  data from sqlite database

Comment: @Prerak - The `yourSavingSQLStatement` would be whatever compiled SQL statement you used to load that particular entry from your database.  You should already be doing this in some part of your code, otherwise you wouldn't be reading anything from the database at all.  For an example of the syntax involved, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429655/using-pointers-in-objective-c-for-nsmutablearray-objects.

Comment: @Prerak - Honestly, though, if you're having problems with SQLite, I'd suggest ditching it and going with Core Data.  Every device in the field now supports Core Data, and you can cut a lot of code by using it.  Not only that, but you'll most likely realize some significant performance improvements by using Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Prerak i think this will help you something..and solve your problem 
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: For BLOB should i need to bind my NSData to blob while saving or retriving data

Comment: i think yes but not sure...few days before i was facing with the same problem with BLOB in one of my app....then i changed my datatype of image to NSString type..thats the reason i suggest u with string datatype....anyways Good Luck!